# Where can I find log of System program problem?

Tags: log, bug-reporting

Every time I turn on my computer, I will meet many dialogues saying:

[image]

But after I click `Report problem`, it disappears and nothing more happens.

Where can I find log for those problem ?

Comment: you can check your system logs present in `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: There are too many lines in `/var/log/syslog` and how can I locate those problems?

Answer (score 1):

To view different types of logs, for like troubleshooting purposes the best way is to use `Log File Viewer` which is a GUI interface, that can be used to view different types of logs.

In your case particular open this `Log File Viewer` and then you will get an option stating `syslog` then double click on this option to view syslogs.

To troubleshoot your problem if this problem arises during startup of your system, Restart your system then view the logs for error messages. (You can take hint from the date and time stamp recorded in the log files.)

Or you can also use the `tail` command to view logs.

`tail -f /var/log/syslog`

-f : it will show logs which are dynamically added later on.

or to view a number of logs use:

`tail -n 100 -f /var/log/syslog`

-n : number of lines to display (In the above case it's 100.)